# Get a guest user by userPrincipalName with Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am playing with Microsoft Graph to access Azure Active Directory from my application, using the REST API directly (without an SDK).

According to the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_get), I should be able to retrieve a user from their `id` or `userPrincipalName` using `/users/{id | userPrincipalName}`.

This is indeed working, but not for Guest users. With Guest users the `userPrincipalName` is something like `name_originaldomain#EXT#@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com`, and trying to get the user results in a `404 Not Found`.

This is the code I am currently using:

```cs
graphClient = new HttpClient();
graphClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/");
graphClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"{token.TokenType} {token.AccessToken}");

HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(
    HttpMethod.Get,
    $"users/{Uri.EscapeUriString(username)}"
);

HttpResponseMessage response = await graphClient.SendAsync(request);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<UserResult>();
}
// I am here with a 404
```

Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Comment: I know I can retrieve the user by email, and it is the workaround I currently put in place for Guest users, but I fear getting the email from the UPN (the only information I have) is not a robust situation in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to URL Encode the `userPrincipalName`. Otherwise you're effectively passing `name_originaldomain` since the `#` designates everything beyond that point as a [URI Fragment](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5).

Try using `name_originaldomain%23EXT%23%40mydomain.onmicrosoft.com`

Comment: I supposed `Uri.EscapeUriString` would to the trick, but it resulted I should use `System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode` instead. Thanks Marc.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative is to create a bigger query that also queries on the `mail` property with the guest user's email address (or in your case what you have as "name@originaldomain").  For guest users, we set the mail property to the guest's email address.

`../users?$filter=mail eq 'name@originaldomain'`

Hope this helps,