# userPrincipalName cant be used to query Graph

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

In AzureAD my user has the following user name: `firstName.Surname@live.se`

I am assuming this is the `principalUserName` but when I query Microsoft Graph, it says it doesn't exist:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/firstName.Surname@live.se
```

When I use the `id` (GUID) instead, I get the `user` returned and I can see that the `userPrincipalName` is actually `firstName.Surname_live.se#EXT#@firstNameSurnamelive.onmicrosoft.com`.

This `userPrincipalName` cannot be used to query Graph. If I try, I get an error that

> "Resource 'firstName.Surname_live.se' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present."

or

> "Resource 'live.se' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present."

This account is the account used when I created my Azure account. I used an existing email. I understand this is the reason it adds the `#EXT#@firstNameSurnamelive.onmicrosoft.com`, but how do I use this when querying Graph? Or maybe this account is not meant to be used for that?

To get around this I could use the `id` instead of `userPrincipalName` to query but I have read that `userPrincipalName` should work. In case I switch to `id`, how do I get it User has been created by the authorization process?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a guest user by userPrincipalName with Microsoft Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46951238/get-a-guest-user-by-userprincipalname-with-microsoft-graph)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The address `firstName.Surname@live.se` is not an AAD account, it's a consumer Microsoft Account (aka Outlook.com, XBox Live). You're seeing a `userPrincipalName` of `firstName.Surname_live.se#EXT#@firstNameSurnamelive.onmicrosoft.com` because they're a "Guest" user in your AAD tenant.

The reason you're getting this error is that `firstName.Surname_live.se#EXT#@firstNameSurnamelive.onmicrosoft.com` contains reserved characters that need to be URL Encoded. The `#` in particular causes issues because it signifies the start of a URI Fragment. Fragments are entirely client-side and *not sent to the server*; meaning Microsoft Graph literally receives nothing after `firstname.surname_live.se`.

To resolve this, URL Encode the `userPrincipalName` so it becomes `firstName.Surname_live.se%23EXT%23%40firstNameSurnamelive.onmicrosoft.com`. You can then use it to properly call into Microsoft Graph:

```
/v1.0/users/firstName.Surname_live.se%23EXT%23%40firstNameSurnamelive.onmicrosoft.com
```

Comment: I have tried URL Encoding my guest's UPN and I still get the same error. Is there anything else that needs to be done, or any documentation explaining this?