# Getting response : Resource 'Random_ObjectID' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present. Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I am using azure Graph api to perform Create-Delete operations on Azure Active directory User and Group.

Following are the APIs I am using

```
User : https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
Group : https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups
```

I am acquiring a token for my application by using PublicClientApplication and aquireToken method with UserNamePasswordParameters + token from cache using acquireTokenSilently method. (MSAL4J library)

I am running the application continuously for around 50 Hrs

But after 40-45Hrs later api giving exception/Response for both User and Group like :

```
Resource 'Random_ObjectID' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.
```

[Attached server side audit log for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGbfB.jpg)

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Has the user or group existed for a long time when you try to delete it?

Comment: @juunas Once I create user I have kept sleep for 10 secs before deleting the user or group

Comment: In this case I am creating user/group which is existed on server for around 10-15 secs.

Comment: Ah, you might be running into an issue where something isn't quite ready in MS Graph. Have you tried implementing a retry for this?

Comment: I haven't tried for retry. I will try this. 
But wanted to know is there any configuration at Azure side I can change to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the possibile causes of the error:

- The problem can either be due to throttling when the requests taking
  long time or if you are trying to make frequent patch calls and may
  happen if your client app is not waiting long enough for the
  operation/replication to complete.

> Note:Firstly please ensure that is  group id and user id are valid  and
> not exchanged by mistake and please check if their usage is required in particular queries.

- Also some api endpoints may not be supported using the v1.0 version .Please check with the Beta version in those cases .
- Please Try `retry-after` logic for exponential increase in retry time
  as in [Microsoft Graph throttling g |
  Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling)

Also when using where or filter object sometimes may take  too much time when many user objects exist.

Please check operations performed by wrapping in a Try and Catch block to handle the error and using without the quey filter where it can be like below:

```
   try
    {
        //operations like Get-AzureAdUser -ObjectId $UPN  rather using the query filters  
 
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
```

The error is usual in some cases where an object is passed to the ObjectId parameter.Instead try with DomainName of your object while passing the ObjectId.
Also please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50024530/userprincipalname-cant-be-used-to-query-graph).

**References**

1. [authentication - Resource 'GUID value here' does not exist ...- Stack
   Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56546947/resource-guid-value-here-does-not-exist-or-one-of-its-queried-reference-proper)
2. [Known issues with Microsoft Graph - Microsoft Graph | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#some-limitations-apply-to-query-parameters)