# Get a guest user by userPrincipalName with Microsoft Graph SDK with Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have the same problem described here: [Get a guest user by userPrincipalName with Microsoft Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46951238/get-a-guest-user-by-userprincipalname-with-microsoft-graph). I want to get a guest user from Graph but I do it with SDK, i.e. a Graph Client, and I use Kotlin. The solution provided in the above mentioned thread does not help me. I still get a 404 Not Found Response even though I am replacing `#` with `%23`.

My code looks like this:

```kotlin
val upn = "hans.muster_somecompany.com%23EXT%23@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com"
client.users(upn)
    .buildRequest()
    .select(USER_FIELDS)
    .get()
```

I've also tried `val upn = "hans.muster_somecompany.com%23EXT%23%40mydomain.onmicrosoft.com"`. Same result.

I am sure that the account exists. When I use the same query in Graph Explorer the user can be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When encoding the UPN first it works.

```kotlin
val upn = "hans.muster_somecompany.com#EXT#@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com"
val upnEncoded = UriUtils.encodePathSegment(
    upn,
    StandardCharsets.UTF_8
)
// upnEncoded is now "hans.muster_somecompany.com%23EXT%23@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com"
client.users(upnEncoded)
    .buildRequest()
    .select(USER_FIELDS)
    .get()
```

The confusing piece for me was that the controller removes `#` and everything that comes afterwards. This resulted in "hans.muster_somecompany.com". When encoding the `#` "manually" and handing that over to the client, the result was "hans.muster_somecompany.com%25%23EXT%25%23@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com" which didn't work either. So, finally, the problem wasn't really Graph but how the client/controller handle the request parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Try replace `#` with `%23` and encode `%` => `%2523`

```
val upn = "hans.muster_somecompany.com%2523EXT%2523@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com"
client.users(upn)
    .buildRequest()
    .select(USER_FIELDS)
    .get()
```

Comment: No, unfortunately that doesn't work either.